# How do I get C++ class instances using ctags?

Tags: c++, ctags, exuberant-ctags

For e.g. I define a C++ class like this:

```
class cat : public animal
{
  public:
    cat(const char* nameString) : m_name(nameString) {}
    ~cat(){}
    const char* getName() {return m_name.c_str();}

 private:
    std::string m_name;
};
```

Later:

```
cat kitty("Garfield");
printf("%s", kitty.getName());
```

For the example code above, [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) could tell me the inheritance, members, methods, access type (public, private) etc.

But how can I find out that kitty is an instance of cat?

Comment: std::type_info   will help?

Comment: It seems like folks are answering the wrong question.  As I understand it, this question isn't about determining type information at run-time.  The question is about getting [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) to identify the type of the instance `kitty`.   @ruben2020: is that correct?

Comment: Yes, this is about using ctags.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::cout << "kitty is a: " << typeid(kitty).name() << '\n';
```

but, as you can [see](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name), could be not exactly what you want.

> Returns an implementation defined null-terminated character string
>   containing the name of the type. No guarantees are given, in
>   particular, the returned string can be identical for several types and
>   change between invocations of the same program.

You can [compare](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/operator_cmp) the `typeid` with other know types, like `cat`.

And you can make it in the same direction/style you have with the object names, and include a virtual function in `Animal` :

```
virtual string whatAnimal()const{return "animal";}
```

and in derived classes:

```
string whatAnimal()const override {return "cat";}
```

Now you have complete control over the string you what for each type, not related to the name convention you use in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get the class name of an object with typeid. However, compiler will magle the name, so you should demangle it appropriately at runtime.

An example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cxxabi.h>

class cls {};

void main(){
    cls obj;
    int status;
    char * demangled_name = abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(obj).name(),0,0,&status);
    std::cout << demangled_name << std::endl;
    free(demangled_name);
    return;
}
```

will output:

```
   cls
```

Answer (score 0):

Directly answering your question of how to check if kitty is an instance of cat can be done this way:

```
if(typeid(cat) == typeid(kitty))
    // do something if kitty is a cat
```

Note, `typeid(YourClass).name()` returns `nYourClass`, where n is the length of the class name.